# Tables associated with views, explicitly highlight

Tags: sql-server

I need to identify all TABLES associated with a view. The mast view is quite complex and has many sub views, which in turn connected by yet more views.

I found the below code that states the parent child relationship but i need to show explicitly which is a view and which is a table. Could someone help me enhance this?

Do I use type_id or something like where xtype = 'V' , xtype = 'TT

```
 DECLARE @ViewName VARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @ViewName = 'MarketAtAGlance';

    select * from 

    (


    WITH deps ( parent, child ) AS ( SELECT v.name ,
                sed.referenced_entity_name
         FROM   sys.sql_expression_dependencies sed
                INNER JOIN sys.views AS v ON sed.referencing_id = v.object_id
         WHERE  v.name = ISNULL(@ViewName, v.name)
         UNION ALL
         SELECT v.name ,
                sed.referenced_entity_name
         FROM   sys.sql_expression_dependencies sed
                INNER JOIN sys.views AS v ON sed.referencing_id = v.object_id
                INNER JOIN deps ON deps.child = v.name ) SELECT   parent ,
             child FROM     deps ORDER BY parent ,
             child;
    )
    a
```

Comment: Is there a link to a downloadable version of the database you're using (with sensitive information obfuscated) so we can try and reproduce what you're doing?

Comment: Unfortunately no I do not.